# How to put group prices instead of regular prices

Tags: price

I want to show my group prices. `Magento` doesnt show my group prices if they are bigger than regular price.

I have differents prices for differents groups of customer, we are a wholesaler. So I only want show the group price that correspond at the customer group.

For example:

> regular price (for regular customer group): 1€.
>   wholesale 1 (for wholesale 1 group): 0.90€.
>   wholesale 2 for wholesale 2 group): 1.20€.

Is it possible to not show regular price anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Regular price is always greater than other prices.
If your regular price in 100 for 1 qty of the product than the group price will be like 90 for 1 qty of product.

If your other price is greater than the regular price, It the wrong concept for eCommerce.

Comment: I have differents prices for differents groups of customer, we are a wholesaler. So I only want show the group price that correspond at the customer group. 

for example:

regular price (for regular customer group): 1€
wholesale 1 (for wholesale 1 group): 0.90€
wholesale 2 for wholesale 2 group): 1.20€

is it possible to not show regular price anymore?

Comment: @LeonardoDavidVirgone Did you find a solution for this?